# How to parse an associative arrray in php into a List VIew Builder with flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

This is my associative array in php:

```
{"No":"020474","name":"Ayuk Baye"}
{"No":"08273","name":"Cedrick"}
{"No":"08274","name":"Ayuk Baye"}
{"No":"08275","name":"Ayu Rebecca"}
{"No":"08276","name":"Raymond"}
{"No":"08277","name":"Jolie"}
{"No":"08278","name":"Prince"}
{"No":"08474","name":"Ayuk Baye"}
```

I need help in parsing this data into a listView Builder with flutter.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, the backend language doesn't matter. At all, so your question is basically asking 2 things.

1. How to parse Json in Flutter
2. How to draw a list in flutter

For #1 you can use json serialiser. The json content above is not valid, but if you put it in an array then it will be valid.

```json
[
   {"No":"020474","name":"Ayuk Baye"}{"No":"08273","name":"Cedrick"},
   {"No":"08274","name":"Ayuk Baye"}{"No":"08275","name":"Ayu Rebecca"},
   {"No":"08276","name":"Raymond"}{"No":"08277","name":"Jolie"},
   {"No":"08278","name":"Prince"}{"No":"08474","name":"Ayuk Baye"}
]
```

Now that you have valid JSON you can use the [Json serialise docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json). Once you have a list of items you can move on to 2.

Where you simply use a list view to show your list.

```dart
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
    Container(child: 
       Text(myJsonList[index].name))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Create a model class for your json resopnce**

*search for json to dart converter online and make a model class for the responce*

**2) Get your responce from API**

*Like this: -*

```
Future<http.Response> getdata() {
  return http.get(Uri.parse('your http end point'));
}
```

**3) Convert the response into a custom Dart object**

```
return YourModelClassName.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

**4) Fetch the data on desired page with initState**

> Your class should be stateful class

*somting like this: -*

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<YourModelClass> getdata;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata = getdata();
  }
  // ···
}
```

**5) Show your data with futurebuilder**

*Refer the code below*

```
FutureBuilder<Album>(
  future: futureAlbum,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return 
        //Show your listview.builder here
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
)
```

**5) Show your data in listview builder**

*Refer this code below*

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  itemCount: entries.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      //Here you can show your data with the help of the model class
      //You can you the 'index' to iterate throug every data
    );
  }
);
```

**For more information refer these documents**

[Fetching data from internet](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

[Listview Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

*Thank you*

Comment: does this fix your issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FutureBuilder` to get the data, then pass it in your ListView

```
 FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
    future: getUser, //your service to get the data from API
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [],
          ),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<User> userList = snapshot.data;
        return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>   Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]),
             itemCount: userList.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                 User user = userList[index];
                 return Container(
                    child: Text(user.name)
                 )
             }
         );
         }
     }
)
```

Comment: I put more example how to pass the data to ListView, hope its help you.