# How to append data into a Future<List<Adds>>

Tags: flutter, api, mobile-application, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to create a on scroll data load. currently I am getting data(ad list) from a api call as a `Future<List<Ads>>`

in scroll listener function I just want to append next page data list.

there was a example of doing it with a list, I just want to do the same with a Future list

```
items.addAll(List.generate(42, (index) => 'Inserted $index'));
```

Comment: So you are getting data in a ```Future<List<Adds>>``` and you want to append that to a ```List<Adds>``` ?

Comment: @HamzaMogni I want append data to Future<List<Ads>> not to a List<Ads>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358518/13912777 Hope this help your issue Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can render a Future, that's why we use a FutureBuilder. Well you will have to convert your API response to a List<Ads>, and then append that to your currently shown List.

Comment: @HamzaMogni can I append a normal list into a futurebuilder ?

Comment: @IrushiNathashaKuruppu yes, just await for the response, convert it to a dart object and append it to your initial list (the one futurebuilder is listening to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
Future<List<Ads>> appendElements(Future<List<Ads>> listFuture, List<Ads> elementsToAdd) async {
  final list = await listFuture;
  list.addAll(elementsToAdd);
  return list;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
appendedListFuture = appendElements(items, yourItemsToAdd);
```